# SQL Select maxDate in SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_MyProcedure]    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MyProcedure] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@StartDate  NVARCHAR(19),
@EndDate    NVARCHAR(19)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

 Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @FirstQuery nvarchar(1500);
DECLARE @SecondQuery nvarchar(1500);
DECLARE @TSQL nvarchar(4000);



SET @FirstQuery =
    '
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,
    ''
    SELECT * FROM Server.Table
    WHERE Name IN 
    (SELECT Tagname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM LocalServer.MyServer.dbo."NameList"
    WHERE LOCATION = ''''X'''' AND SOURCE = ''''Y'''') AND TIMESTAMP >= ''''' + @StartDate + ''''' AND TIMESTAMP < ''''' + @EndDate + ''''''')';
```

My question is: How could I include max(date) in the code, so the @startDate would be compared to the latest available date for a column in the DB instead of todays date. 
The code you see works fine, however when I choose a later date than the last existing date in the DB the query runs for a while before it returns an error that no columns were found.

Thanks in advance for any suggetions.

HELP.
The following part of the code doesn't work, but I can't figure out why. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you

```
     -- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @FirstQuery nvarchar(1500);
DECLARE @SecondQuery nvarchar(1500);
DECLARE @TSQL nvarchar(4000);
DECLARE @MaxTimeStamp nvarchar(19);


SET@MaxTimeStamp =
'SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) From OPENQUERY(LinkedServer)'


IF @StartDate <= @MaxTimeStamp
BEGIN

SET @FirstQuery =
    '
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,
    ''
    SELECT * FROM Server.Table
    WHERE Name IN 
    (SELECT Tagname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM LocalServer.MyServer.dbo."NameList"
    WHERE LOCATION = ''''X'''' AND SOURCE = ''''Y'''') AND TIMESTAMP >= ''''' + @StartDate + ''''' AND TIMESTAMP < ''''' + @EndDate + ''''''')';

END
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could replace it with a subquery:

```
(select max(timestamp) from NameList)
```

If this is a stored procedure, you might want to put this in a variable, something like:

```
declare @MaxTimestamp datetime;
select @MaxTimestamp = max(TimeStamp) from NameList

-- in your query, something like
      coalesce(@StartTime, maxTimeStamp)
```

If performance is an issue, try adding an index on `NameList(Location, Source, Timestamp)`.

Comment: It seems to me that using `coalesce` could return different records than what was requested. I think it would be better to continue returning no columns, just more quickly.

Comment: Never mind... that's actually what OP asked for. I read it wrong. :-\

Comment: I was trying out both code, could you Jeff please post again what you posted before? I need some time to try it out. However it seems like i have some problems with the types defined

Comment: Thank you for the answer, as soon as i try it out I will come back to it.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg Could you please post again the code you posted earlier? thank you

Comment: I couldn't make it work, I will post the full procedure, and then the way I edited, maybe I edited it in the wrong place. If you have any suggestions can you have a look over it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @maxDate datetime;
SELECT @maxDate = MAX(timestamp) FROM OPENQUERY(...);

IF @StartDate <= @maxDate
BEGIN
  --Your original query here
END
```

Comment: Thank you, it will take me some time to try it, but I will definitely come back whether was it useful or not. Thank you again